# Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows in plot_model function in r

Tags: r, visualization

trying to graph a predicated marginal effects plot of an OLS regression with fixed effects. However, I keep getting this error:

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 7182, 9176

My data frame is too big to provide a reproducible example, but `latentmean` is my DV, `norm_supp_balance` is my IV. The rest are controls.

```
model2 <- plm(latentmean ~ lag(norm_supp_balance) + logGDPpc+ logpop + intrastate 
       +polity5+ exclpop, 
                  data = workingdata,
                  index = c("state", "year"), 
                  model = "within",
                  effect = "twoways")
        
plot_model(model2,type = "pred", terms = "norm_supp_balance")
```

Comment: It is unclear to the reader where functions `plm` and `plot_model` come from as both are not contained in the base R distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The columns of dataset must have equal number of rows.
It is caused by what I mention to you.
With the function nrow() can you view the rows number